# Nhibernate: Conditional And Clause in QueryOver()

Tags: c#, nhibernate

this is my query:

```
 var query = _session.QueryOver<CRMPhoneCall>(); 
            if (filter.Subject != null)
            {
                query.JoinQueryOver<CRMPhoneCall_Subject>
                        (p => p.PhoneCall_Subject)
                    .JoinQueryOver(d => d.Subject)
                    .And(s => s.Id == filter.Subject.Id) //check filter.Subject.Id has value else The condition does not apply
                    .And(s => s.Parent == null) //check filter.OnlyMainSubject has true else The condition does not apply;
            }
```

two separate if for check filter.Subject And filter.OnlyMainSubject does not work(duplicate instance in QueryOver)

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = session.QueryOver<CRMPhoneCall>();
if (filter.Subject != null)
{
    var subjectQuery = query.JoinQueryOver<CRMPhoneCall_Subject>(p => p.PhoneCall_Subject)
        .Where(s => s.Subject == filter.Subject);
    if (filter.OnlyMainSubject)
    {
        subjectQuery.JoinQueryOver(ps => ps.Subject)
            .Where(s => s.Parent == null); //check filter.OnlyMainSubject has true else The condition does not apply;
    }
}
```